# how to read contents of MAT-file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a .mat file that contains the training data, i.e., the histograms of the almost 1000 image samples. i want to analyze that program to plot histograms of some other images,
however if i open that file in mat-lab I'm getting some odd language code..!!
How to read contents?

Comment: `MAT` files don't contain program but MATLAB objects. So, basically they contain the data, not the code. You can load the data using `load` command.

Comment: what kind of objects/data? i need to create same type of file for other kind of images, i.e., wanna plot histogram for other those.

Comment: you cannot reverse-engineer a mat file, meaning you have to know how the 1000 values (histogram bin data) were produced in order to do the same to other images. Please rephrase question, post, title to reflect what is your problem, what did you try and why is it not working.

Comment: reverse-engineering in the sense i just want to analyze that file, so that i can develop a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `histData.mat` is the file name. Then you either drag that file into MATLAB command window or write `load histData.mat`, provided the MATLAB directory is same as the directory of your MAT-file.

This will load your data of 1000 histogram samples and then you can use `plot` command.

Comment: yeah i got to know how to load MAT files, but i need to analyze manually. I mean i need to create same file for other kind of images.

Comment: Read the images in your directory using a for loop and in that loop calculate histogram. After you have calculated histogram for all the images, just save the data by writing: `save your_filename.mat`. If you are new to MATLAB, this will require some work but I am sure everything is available online.